# Let $A$ be a set such that each member of $A$ is a non-empty set. Then $A \times X \neq x$ for all $X \in A, x \in \bigcup A$.

Tags: set-theory

I tried so hard but to no avail while proving the statement:

> Let $A$ be a set such that each member of $A$ is a non-empty set. Then $A \times X \neq x$ for all $X \in A, x \in \bigcup A$. Here $A \times X$ is the Cartesian product of $A$ and $X$.

Please shed some light! Thank you for your help!

Comment: The title is confusing: should it be understood that $\;A\;$ is a set all of which elements are *also* sets? And if this is the case, then all these are subsets... **of what** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't understand your comment... what object in the set theoretic universe is *not* a set? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Most of them in naive set theory, for example. When teaching elementary set theory, one of the main stresses is, usually, the difference between sets and objects of a set, the notation used for them, etc. That is why, without further explanation, I find this question's header confusing. And behold the tag...

Comment: @DonAntonio: It's more of a historical context about this specific user's questions in this case... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps, yet I don't know, or remember, this used from before...

Comment: In my circumstance, I study set theory under ZF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is a collection of sets, $X$ is a set in $A$ and $x$ is an
element. $x = A\times X$ has to violate regularity. Proof.

There is some $K \in A$ with $x \in K$ and some $y \in X$.
Thus $x \in K \in \{K,y\} \in \{\{K\}, \{K,y\}\} = (K,y) \in A \times X = x$.

Comment: You essentially said that there is no set $x$ such that $x \in a \in b \in c \in x$ for all $a,b,c$. It is obvious that $x \in a \in x$ is wrong for all $a,x$. I'm trying to prove that $x \in a \in b \in c \in x$ is wrong for all $a,b,c,x$.

Comment: I got it. Let $S=\{x,a,b,c\}$. Then $S \cap x = \{c\},S \cap c = \{b\},S \cap b = \{a\},S \cap a = \{x\}$. As a result, $\neg \exists m \in S, m \cap S = \varnothing$. This violates the Axiom of Regularity. Many thanks for you!

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is not empty and from $X\in A$ it follows that $X$ is not empty, so let $y$ denote some element of $X$.

Now let $x\in a\in A$.

Then $\{\{a\},\{a,y\}\}=\langle a,y\rangle\in A\times X$.

Assumption $A\times X=x$ then leads to $\langle a,y\rangle\in x$.

But then $x\in a\in\cup\cup x$ so that $x\overline{\in}x$.

However, with induction on $\overline{\in}$ it can easily be shown that:$$\forall x[\neg x\overline{\in}x]$$

So if the axiom of regularity is accepted (which makes induction on $\overline{\in}$ legitimate) then the assumption $A\times X=x$ must be rejected.

Here $\overline{\in}$ denotes the transitive closure of $\in$.

Comment: What does $\overline{\in}$ mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot it denotes the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of relation $\in$.

Comment: This is the second time I've seen you use this notation. Is that new? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @AsafKaragila encountered in my first (1975) book that seriously is about sets (Verzamelingen, D. van Dalen, H.C. Doets, H.C.M. de Swart). I have always been in the assumption that it was quite common to write $\overline{R}$ for transitive closure of relation $R$. Btw, the book (very nice) is really falling apart in pieces, but I keep it together.

Comment: Thank you your answer @drhab. Although I don't know what transitive closure is, I think your answer essentially said that $x \in a \in b \in c \in x$ is impossible for all $a,b,c,x$. Thus I'm trying to prove that.

Comment: @drhab, I got it. Let $S=\{x,a,b,c\}$. Then $S \cap x = \{c\},S \cap c = \{b\},S \cap b = \{a\},S \cap a = \{x\}$. As a result, $\neg \exists m \in S, m \cap S = \varnothing$. This violates the Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: Small thing: it is indeed enough to observe that the sets $S\cap y$ where $y\in S$ are not empty. So it is enough to state that e.g. $c\in S\cap x$. But it is wrong to state that $S\cap x=\{c\}$ because it is not excluded yet that e.g. also $a\in x$.

Comment: Many thanks @drhab for pointing out my subtle mistake :v